# Associate string with plot marker

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm wondering, that is it possible in mathematica to associate plot legends with plot markers. For example let's say we have a Legended datas. Is it possible, to use the same marker for the data if the legend is a certain string?
Example:

```
plots = Table[Symbol["plot" <> ToString@i], {i, 1, 2}];
Rsquared = {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4}}
filteredLength = {{100, 200}, {300, 400}}
filteredName = {{"foo", "bar"}, {"bar", "foo"}}
data = Legended[{{#, #2}}, #3] & @@@ (Join @@ 
     Thread /@ Transpose[{filteredLength, Rsquared, filteredName}]);
data = Partition[data, 2]

Do[plots[[i]] = 
  ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[11], 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[14], PlotMarkers -> Automatic];
 Print[plots[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

The thing i want, that if the "foo" appears as a legend, it has to be associated with a certain plot marker, on every plot.

If you know how to solve it, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort input data by legend labels:

```
Do[plots[[i]] = ListPlot[SortBy[data[[i]], Last], 
   Joined -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[11], 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[14], 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}], {i, 1, 2}]

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ plots, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]